# How can I test whether Django is running in debug mode?

Tags: django

My settings file has:

```
DEBUG = True
```

The obvious method:

```
if DEBUG:
    print 'debug'
```

Does not seem to work:

```
global name 'DEBUG' is not defined
```

Comment: You need to go via `settings.DEBUG`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you need to do:

```
from django.conf import settings

print(settings.DEBUG)
```

Comment: I am new to django. Can You please explain where I can write this to check my settings.I tried in Python console but it is not giving the right value back.

Comment: @LalitSharma In `python manage.py shell` of your Django `manage.py`

Comment: @DBedrenko thank you, that worked just fine. I was adding it in view and returning the value as api result. That was a mess.