# How can I know whether the code is running under testing? Globally?

Tags: django, debugging, testing, environment-variables

Now that we can know whether the code in running under DEBUG mode:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16648628/2544762

But at the same time, when we run the code in a unittest, we always got `debug == False`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/overview/#other-test-conditions

In my own case, I just really want to make some code under debug condition, and want it to be tested with `debug == True`, how can I do?

So, is there any way to detect whether the code is running with test? In any place.

Comment: Just use an environment variable?

Comment: Found a duplicated question with a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11366998/2544762

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way to detect whether the code is running with test?

Yes.

You want a flag that has different semantics from
the one django offers. So define a new one.

You could `touch` a file and test its existence,
or always write 0 or 1 to a file,
define an env var read by `os.getenv( ... )`,
accept a `sys.argv` option,
define a global.
You have a Turing machine at your disposal.
The possibilities are endless.

Answer (score 0):

My case is that I want to know whether the settings.DEBUG is set to True.

If I use:

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_01(self):
        from django.conf import settings
        print(settings.DEBUG)
```

The output is always False, whatever I actually set.

This documentation told us why: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/overview/#other-test-conditions

But in my case, we can have another choice to read the setting:

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_01(self):
        import importlib
        raw_settings = importlib.import_module(os.environ.get('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'))
        print(raw_settings.DEBUG)
```

In this way, we can get around the problem.